# What am I missing/How do I rehang my closet's bi-fold doors?

Tags: doors, closet

The last owner did a lot of home projects, and I've determined that they did a terrible job on just about everything.  So keep that in mind here, and I won't be surprised if the answer is "redo everything yourself".  But anyway:

I have standard bi-fold closet doors.  One side was not hung properly - when the door closed all the way it would hang "low" and the top would easily slip off the track.  Eventually the door just fell off the track.  I finally got around to re-hanging it and was completely unable.  When I put the door back in the bracket on the bottom, the top peg is only high enough to just graze the top bracket.  It is simply too short to put the door back up.

I initially assumed that something might have gone wrong with the bottom bracket (a shim moved out of place?) causing the whole thing to lose some height.  However, after close inspection, this doesn't seem to be the case or even possible.  I looked at the other door (which hangs fine) and noticed that while the fallen door only has a peg on the bottom, the other door appears to have something more like a screw.  As a result, perhaps a piece fell off the fallen door when it fell?  Its been a few weeks, so if a piece came loose it's probably gone (this is a toddler's room).

**Did I lose a piece, resulting in the door no longer fitting in the track?  Or is something else wrong with this door?  Either way, what is the best way to get this thing hung up again?**

Here is the bottom bracket:

[image]

And the top bracket.  It is definitely a bit loose and has a poorly-executed shim:

[image]

Here is the bottom of the bi-fold door, which is just a fixed peg:

[image]

And for reference, here's the bottom of the other door, which works fine (and looks like a screw, not a peg).

[image]

Comment: How about a picture of the upper track. The bottom of the door in question is exactly like the ones I have and they work great.

Comment: @JACK I added in a picture of the top.  I checked a few other bi-fold closets in my house and they have the screw-like bottom pegs like the working door in the picture above.  I suppose it is possible that the screw goes over the peg, and therefore the screw-piece is missing, but I'm suspicious that this door was always different than all the other doors and that is part of why it never hung properly (and probably part of why I can't re-hang it now).

Comment: Does the bottom pin in the door screw out? It looks like a hex head on the shaft. Your upper track is different than mine, mine has a clamp that holds the pin in it.

Comment: @JACK I think you just solved all the mysteries... that was a hex head and when I turned it, the shaft lengthened just like you might hope!  However when I tried to rehang the door it was still the same height, and when I took it back down the shaft had "collapsed" down again. I'm guessing it is broken and needs to be replaced, which also explains why it fell.  Still, that answers my question if you want to repost that as an answer for me to accept.

Comment: You can  unscrew the pin from the nylon housing and screw a nut onto the pin and reinsert the pin onto the nylon housing. Raise the door by unscrewing one of the nuts ...... or just buy a new part. Good luck

Comment: the last picture is correct ... the other door should have the same device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prop the door into the upper track and then unscrew the bottom pin to tighten up the door. you might want to tighten up the upper track and fix that shim job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did loose the pin, some big box stores do Cary some models, but I have made them with a bolt and washers in the past. You don’t want to replace the door for a part that can be purchased or made for less than 5$. Usually with Buford’s the reason they come out of the track is the top pivot is to far away from the jamb.  I say this as your photo looks like it is fixed.